# Matcher/Searcher with Glob support

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have data like this:

```py
DATA = {
  "Alfa-1": {...},
  "Beta-1": {...},
  "Beta-2": {...},
  "Delta-1": {...},
  "Delta-2": {...},
  # and so on
}
```

I want to perform extraction, but I want the key to also **support the "glob" syntax**.

So if I specify `["Alfa-1", "Delta-*"]` it should return the data points for `"Alfa-1"`, `"Delta-1"`, and `"Delta-2"`.

ALSO, I want the match to be **case-insensitive**.

So far, this is the code I could come up with:

```py
from fnmatch import fnmatch


DATA = ...  # Declared here for illustrative purposes


def grab(selectors: list[str]) -> dict:
    result = {}
    data_fold = {k.casefold(): k for k in DATA}
    for sel in map(str.casefold, selectors):
        if k := data_fold.get(sel):
            result[k] = DATA[k]
        else:
            result.update({
                k: DATA[k]
                for kf, k in data_fold.items()
                if fnmatch(kf, sel)
            })
    return result
```

Please review my code, is it efficient or not. Or tell me if there's a better way to implement what I need.

Answer (score 3):

#### unnecessary syntax sugar:

- casefold(): Although I highly doubt `lower()` is enough, I assume you really need it and keep it.
- map
- `:=` operators

#### unnecessary if-else:

- `fnmatch` can handle equal situation

#### unnecessary update:

- just use `if fnmatch(kf, sel)` then `result[k] = DATA[k]` is enough

#### example code:

- simple nested loop:

```
def grab(selectors: list[str]) -> dict:
    result = {}
    for rule in selectors:
        for k,v in DATA.items():
            if fnmatch(k.casefold(), rule.casefold()):
                result[k] = v
    return result
```

- <del>fancy</del> one-liner:

```
def grab(selectors: list[str]) -> dict:
    return {k:v for rule in selectors for k,v in DATA.items() if fnmatch(k.casefold(), rule.casefold())}
```

- test:

```
DATA = {
  "Alfa-1": 0,
  "Beta-1": 1,
  "Beta-2": 2,
  "Delta-1": 3,
  "Delta-2": 4,
}
print(grab(["Alfa-1", "Delta-*"]))
print(grab(["alfa-1", "delta-*"]))
```

- result:

```
{'Alfa-1': 0, 'Delta-1': 3, 'Delta-2': 4}
{'Alfa-1': 0, 'Delta-1': 3, 'Delta-2': 4}
```

Comment: Wouldn't removing the `if k := DATA.get()` part degrades all searches into O(N)? I was aiming to leverage the case when the function is called with an exact match, so the search would be O(1).

Answer (score 3):

I think it may be a good idea to leverage `fnmatch.filter()` instead of writing an inner loop on a bare `fnmatch`.

Add type hints, including - potentially - a generic type hint for your data. Since you haven't given us enough information to justify `DATA` being a global, don't leave it as a global.

Write unit tests.

Separate the function into the "hard part" (key filtration) and the "easy part" (dictionary key multi-lookup).

### Suggested

```py
import fnmatch
from typing import Collection, Iterable, TypeVar

ValueT = TypeVar('ValueT')


def glob_filter_overlapping(
    selectors: Iterable[str],
    keys: Collection[str],
) -> Iterable[str]:
    for selector in selectors:
        yield from fnmatch.filter(names=keys, pat=selector.casefold())


def glob_select_all(
    selectors: Iterable[str],
    data: dict[str, ValueT],
) -> list[ValueT]:
    keys = glob_filter_overlapping(selectors=selectors, keys=data.keys())
    return [data[key] for key in set(keys)]


def test() -> None:
    data = {
        'Alpha-1': 1,
        'Beta-1': 2,
        'Beta-2': 3,
        'Delta-1': 4,
        'Delta-2': 5,
    }
    actual = glob_select_all(selectors=('*lta*', '*-2'), data=data)
    assert sorted(actual) == [3, 4, 5]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

### Preprocessing

If you have

- a lot of `DATA`, and/or
- you re-apply the same set of selectors for several different `DATA` inputs,

you may benefit from pre-compiling your multiple selectors into one regular expression. This will have different performance characteristics that I have not measured.

```py
import fnmatch
import re
from typing import Iterable, TypeVar

ValueT = TypeVar('ValueT')


def preprocess_globs(
    selectors: Iterable[str],
) -> re.Pattern:
    pattern = '|'.join(
        fnmatch.translate(selector)
        for selector in selectors
    )
    return re.compile(pattern=pattern, flags=re.I)


def pattern_select_all(
    pattern: re.Pattern,
    data: dict[str, ValueT],
) -> list[ValueT]:
    return [
        value
        for key, value in data.items()
        if pattern.search(key) is not None
    ]


def test() -> None:
    data = {
        'Alpha-1': 1,
        'Beta-1': 2,
        'Beta-2': 3,
        'Delta-1': 4,
        'Delta-2': 5,
    }
    pat = preprocess_globs(('*lta*', '*-2'))
    actual = pattern_select_all(pattern=pat, data=data)
    assert sorted(actual) == [3, 4, 5]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: Oooh, thanks! I did not realize there's a `fnmatch.filter()` function!

Answer (score 3):

> Is this efficient?

No.

> Let's say I have data like this ...

You introduce a size N python `dict`, similar to a java `HashMap`.

For "generic" globbing, against arbitrary `"*-foo-*"` patterns, this may suffice.

For the "prefix" globs you appear to contemplate, like `"foo-*"`,
it is not appropriate, as there is no reason for each query
to incur O(N) linear scan cost.
Create a new type to store those `k, v` mappings in ordered fashion,
so you can find first match with O(log N) logarithmic cost,
and then read out M subsequent glob matches with O(M) cost.

If we store a million keys in the dictionary,
then a request to retrieve the handful of records matching a glob
shouldn't have to laboriously scan through *all* of those million entries.

## correctness

Additionally, there is an ambiguity in what your datastructure stores.
Speaking on behalf of maintenance engineers who will interact with
your code in coming months, I assert that attempts to store a glob should fail.

```
    DATA["foo-bar"] = "qux"
    DATA["foo-*"] = "baz"  # should raise ValueError, rather than storing baz
```

As presented in the OP, when we return a certain `k` key value
it is ambiguous whether it is being returned due to literal match
or being returned due to a glob pattern match.
Allowing baz to be stored as in the example seems undesirable,
since your interface could no longer retrieve it alone,
we always would *also* get the qux entry.

## datastructure

Your container type should continue to use a `dict` on the inside.
Additionally it should use the `__setitem__`
[protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__)
to store each key in a
[sorted key list](https://pypi.org/project/sortedcontainers).
Use `__delitem__` to ensure the list always matches the set of dictionary keys.

This allows us to use
[.irange_key(start, None)](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html#sortedcontainers.SortedKeyList.irange_key)
to efficiently scan entries matching a glob pattern prefix,
until encountering one for which the glob function returns `False`.

## case insensitive

As long as you're doing all that, you may as well go to the trouble
of case folding keys at the time they are set.
So each key takes double storage: its canonical form, plus downcased form.
On the inside of your new type you would implement it like this:

```
    # input parameters are: k, v
    self.data[k.casefold()] = (k, v)

    # example
    k, v = "foo-Bar", "the value"
    self.data["foo-bar"] = ("foo-Bar", "the value")
```

Now a `.get()` request can immediately fetch a result in O(1) constant time.

This addreses another correctness detail.
We have made it impossible to store conflicting keys, such as `"Foo-BAR"`,
which I submit is a Good Thing.

Comment: As per the "correctness" part, let's say that due to how the data is generated, it's not allowed to use anything but alphanumeric, space, hyphen `-`, and underscore `_` as key. So although the dict itself has no validation as to allowed keys, this mapping is actually not user generated.

Comment: There was some Review Context missing. If there is a [contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) mentioned in a hidden function's """docstring""", or an `assert` in the code, that did not appear in the OP. Please strive to include relevant aspects of the code under study when you present it for review. Declaring an input to be generically of `str` is different from saying it matches a regex. If there is also some "readMe" vs "READme" case insensitivity constraint that is present in the original code, it would be helpful to surface that.